# Error en dimensiones de matrices en Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

Estoy haciendo un programa en Matlab para hacer simulaciones de señales y me arroja el error "Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-2." Desde luego, entiendo que se trata de que lo del lado izquierdo no es de la misma dimensión que lo del lado derecho... Lo que sucede es que he tratado de corregir el error pero no logro hacerlo, siempre me termina arrojando un error análogo.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientación y dejo mi código enseguida (El error me lo arroja en la línea `L(k,k+i)=L(k,k+i-1)*Phi*(ones(1,k+i)-K(k+i));`. Por otra parte, variables como P0, z0, R0 o Phi son solo números reales definidos previamente).

```
%%%%Filtrado%%%
Cpred0=P0;
K0=Cpred0*[P0+R0]^-1;
fil0=K0*z0;
Cfil0=[1-K0]*Cpred0;
pred(1)=Phi*fil0;
Cpred(1)=Phi^2*Cfil0+Q0;
for k=1:n
    K(k)=Cpred(k)*[Cpred(k)+R(k)]^-1;
    fil(k)=pred(k)+K(k)*[z(k)-pred(k)];
    Cfil(k)=[1-K(k)]*Cpred(k);
    pred(k+1)=Phi*fil(k);
    Cpred(k+1)=Phi^2*Cfil(k)+Q(k);
end

%%%%%Suavizamiento de punto fijo N=2%%%%%
for k=1:n
    L(k,k)=Cfil(k);
    pf(k,k)=fil(k);
    Cpf(k,k)=Cfil(k);
end

for k=1:n
    for i=1:2
        kpf(k,k+i)=L(k,k+i-1)*Phi*(Cpred(k+i))^-1;
        L(k,k+i)=L(k,k+i-1)*Phi*(ones(1,k+i)-K(k+i));
        pf(k,k+i)=pf(k,k+i-1)+kpf(k,k+i)*(z(k+i)-pred(k+i));
        Cpf(k,k+i)=Cpf(k,k+i-1)-kpf(k,k+i)*(pred(k+i)+R(k))*kpf(k,k+i);
    end
end
```

Saludos.

Comment: deberías proporcionar un ejemplo que se pueda correr hasta el punto donde te falla, defino los valores que me va pidiendo pero de repente `R` se supone que es un vector. es dificl intentar ayudar si no se proporciona un ejemplo reproducible

Comment: en esta expresión `L(k,k+i)=L(k,k+i-1)*Phi*(ones(1,k+i)-K(k+i));` a izquierda tenés un escalar, a derecha L(...) es escalar, phi es escalar, y porqué definis dos matrices ara restar si todo debería dar un escalar?